# DB2 can't create a simple stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

My real stored procedure is much more complex, but DB2 can't even seem to create a dummy stored procedure that does absolutely nothing (that's why I'm posting this dummy procedure). The procedure is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SIMPLE_DECL_PROC()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE v varchar(16);//the problem is here
END
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
2:59:31  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;ECLARE v varchar(16);<psm_semicolon>, DRIVER=3.57.82
```

The error complains about the declare statement although I can't see anything wrong with it (tried removing the ; at the end but it didn't work).

**If I remove the declare statement, the procedure is created successfully.**

I tried to do this with DBVisualizer as well as SQL Squirrel.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing but I can't find it. Needless to say, I've checked similar questions here on SO and elsewhere.

And finally, we're using DB2 9.7.

Thanks

Comment: What did you set as statement terminator in your client? And remember, it is not the database, but the user...

Comment: Yes, I added a slash (/) at the end and it worked (I had to set the statement separator in the client). It seems that some clients don't require this (e.g pgAdmin for Postgre but I guess pgAdmin knows how to handle this for Postgre). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SQL clients allow to set a so-called statement terminator. This is the character that is at the end of the entire statement. By default most clients use the semicolon (";"). For stored procedures often a different statement terminator needs to be chosen and set. This is because a stored procedure can include multiple SQL statements which are terminated, but only that ouf the entire stored procedure is relevant.

Comment: BTW, I used a statement terminator for Oracle too, but somehow forgotten that it was needed. PgAdmin does not require it for Postgre.